# C++ - Output all possible DNA kmers of a given length

Tags: c++, algorithm, bioinformatics

A "kmer" is a DNA sequence of length K.  A valid DNA sequence (for my purposes) can only contain the 4 following bases: A,C,T,G.  I am looking for a C++ algorithm that simply outputs all possible combinations of these bases *in alphabetical order* into a string array.  For example, if K = 2, The program should generate the following array:

```
kmers[0]  = AA
kmers[1]  = AC
kmers[2]  = AG
kmers[3]  = AT
kmers[4]  = CA
kmers[5]  = CC
kmers[6]  = CG
kmers[7]  = CT
kmers[8]  = GA
kmers[9]  = GC
kmers[10] = GG
kmers[11] = GT
kmers[12] = TA
kmers[13] = TC
kmers[14] = TG
kmers[15] = TT
```

If I'm thinking about this correctly, the problem really breaks down to converting a decimal integer to base 4 then substituting the appropriate bases. I thought I could use itoa for this, but itoa is not C standard, and my compiler did not support it.  I welcome any clever ideas.  Here is my sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

#define K 3

using namespace std;

int main() {

  int num_kmers = pow(4,K);
  string* kmers = NULL;

  /* Allocate memory for kmers array */
  kmers = new string[num_kmers];

  /* Populate kmers array */
  for (int i=0; i< pow(4,K); i++) {

    // POPULATE THE kmers ARRAY HERE                                                                                                                                                         

  }

  /* Display all possible kmers */
  for (int i=0; i< pow(4,K); i++)
    cout << kmers[i] << "\n";

  delete [] kmers;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to use recursion to be flexible (i.e. so that you could change K easily).

```
void populate(int depth, string base, string* kmers, int* kmers_offset)
{
    if(depth == K)
    {
        kmers[*kmers_offset].assign(base);
        (*kmers_offset)++;
    }
    else
    {
        static char bases[] = { 'A', 'C', 'G', 'T' };
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
            populate(depth + 1, base + bases[i], kmers, kmers_offset);
    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
int kmers_offset = 0;
populate(0, "", kmers, &kmers_offset);
```

Cheers.

Comment: Ah hold on, I found a nasty (obvious) bug with that. One second.

Comment: You should really, really, really use a `vector`.

Comment: Oh I fully agree. But I wanted to write something that would fit in with his currently existing code. Obviously if he's not careful this WILL overflow. Vectorize me, cap'n.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to convert decimal to anything, once the user input text has been accepted.

It's also probably a mistake to create an array of strings, which grows exponentially with `K`. Just print the output.

```
char bases[] = { 'A', 'C', 'T', 'G' };
std::vector< int > sequence( K ); // allow dynamic K
std::vector< char > output( K * ( 2 << K * 2 ) ); // flat sequence of sequences
std::vector< char >::iterator out_it = output.begin();

int i;
do {
    // print current sequence
    for ( i = 0; i < K; ++ i ) std::cout << bases[ sequence[ i ] ];
    std::cout << '\n';

    // store current sequence
    for ( i = 0; i < K; ++ i ) * out_it ++ = bases[ sequence[ i ] ];

    // advance to next sequence
    for ( i = K; i > 0; -- i ) {
        // increment the last base that we can
        if ( sequence[ i - 1 ] != sizeof bases - 1 ) {
            ++ sequence[ i - 1 ];
            break;
        }
        // reset bases that can't be incremented
        sequence[ i - 1 ] = 0;
    }
} while ( i > 0 ); // if i <= 0, failed to increment anything, we're done.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately, this is part of a larger bioinformatics application which does require that I store the results in an array.  I am well aware of the dangers of a large K.

Comment: @ned: You can use this to build an array instead of printing the output. But the application would probably be more scalable if you did whatever you could to avoid such arrays. When it comes to large amounts of information, it becomes important to use precious memory for meaningful data and not "fluff."

Answer (score 2):

This seems to me to be a perfect fit for a custom iterator. That way your main program can be simple:

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
v.reserve(kmerIterator<4>::end() - kmerIterator<4>::begin());
std::copy(kmerIterator<4>::begin(), kmerIterator<4>::end(),
    std::back_inserter(v));
```

But, since we have implemented the kmer concept as an interator, we get to use all of the other generic algorithms, too. Since we implemented the kmer iterator as a Random Access Iterator, then finding the i-th kmer is trivial:

```
kmerIterator<4>::begin()[i]
```

Here is my complete program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template<unsigned int n>
class kmerIterator :
    public std::iterator<std::random_access_iterator_tag,
        std::string,
        unsigned int>
{
private:
    typedef kmerIterator k; // 'cause I'm lazy
    difference_type it;
    kmerIterator(difference_type i) : it(i) {}
public:
    kmerIterator() : it() {}
    static k begin() {
        return 0;
    }
    static k end() {
        return difference_type(1) << n*2;
    }
    k& operator++() { ++it; return *this; }
    k operator++(int) { return it++; }
    k& operator--() { --it; return *this; }
    k operator--(int) { return it--; }
    k operator+(difference_type delta) { return it + delta; }
    k operator-(difference_type delta) { return it - delta; }
    difference_type operator-(const k& rhs) { return it - rhs.it; }
    bool operator<(const k& rhs) const { return it < rhs.it; }
    bool operator>(const k& rhs) const { return it > rhs.it; }
    bool operator<=(const k& rhs) const { return it <= rhs.it; }
    bool operator>=(const k& rhs) const { return it >= rhs.it; }
    k operator+=(difference_type delta) { return it+=delta; }
    k operator-=(difference_type delta) { return it-=delta; }
    std::string operator[](difference_type delta) const { return *k(it+delta); }
    std::string operator*() const {
        std::string rz;
        int i = 2*n;
        do {
            i -= 2;
            rz += "ACGT"[(it>>i)&3];
        } while(i);
        return rz;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::copy(kmerIterator<2>::begin(),
        kmerIterator<2>::end(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));

    std::vector<std::string> v;
    v.reserve(kmerIterator<4>::end() - kmerIterator<4>::begin());
    std::copy(kmerIterator<4>::begin(),
        kmerIterator<4>::end(),
        std::back_inserter(v));
    std::cout << v[42] << "\n";
    std::cout << kmerIterator<4>::begin()[56] << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Whoa, this shouldn't be so hard.

```
std::string kmers(int i, int K) {
  static const char* DNA = "ACGT";
  if (K==0) return std::string();
  return DNA[i%4] + kmers(i / 4, K-1);
}

const int K = 2;
int main () {
  for (int i = 0; i != 1<<(2*K); ++i)
    std::cout << "kmers[" << i << "] = " << kmers(i,K) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

class kmer
{
public:
    kmer();
    kmer(std::string &str, int &k) : k_(k), str_(str)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= str_.size() - k_; ++i)
            value_.push_back(str_.substr(i, k_));
    }
    auto value() { return value_; }
    auto size() { return value_.size(); }
private:
    std::vector<std::string_view> value_;
    std::string_view str_;
    int k_;
};

int main()
{
    std::string seq{"AGCTAGCT"};
    kmer k4_mer(seq, 4);
    
    std::cout << "Total " << k4_mer.size() << " mers\n";
    for(auto &i : k4_mer.value())
        std::cout << i << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```